# Unable to Import Data

Tags: postgis, geoserver, ubuntu, import

I am following this [tutorial](http://workshops.opengeo.org/stack-intro/geoserver.html),

but i am not able to get the right username and password to import data. How do I know what the username password is? By default I see tomcat6 as database and username and no password in the textbox. As i am following the tutorial I changed it to username: postgis and password: postgres.

How do I know what my username and password is?

**EDIT**

Import the data in PostGIS, which requires PostGIS connection.

**UPDATE**

Ok so i got the user and passwd but when I am trying to add the shapefile using the Shape File to PostGIS Importer Plugin and having made connection successfully, I am getting this error when I am adding the shapefile.

```
Connecting: host=localhost port=5432 user=admin dbname=shpRepo password='**********' 
Connection succeeded.
Connection: host=localhost port=5432 user=admin dbname=shpRepo password='**********' 
Destination: public.AllQuebecSpecies
Source File: /home/smaranh/development/Biodiversity/biodiversity/shapefile/AllQuebecSpecies
Shapefile type: Point
Postgis type: POINT[2]
Failed SQL begins: "SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO UTF8;
SET STANDARD_CONFORMING_STRINGS TO ON;
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "public"."AllQuebecSpecies" (gid serial PRIMARY KEY,
"family" varchar(50),
"species" varchar(50));
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public','AllQuebecSpecies','the_geom','-1"
Failed in pgui_exec(): ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 7: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public','AllQuebecSpecies','the_ge...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Shapefile import failed.
```

Can somebody tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: do you have pgadmin III http://www.pgadmin.org/visualtour14.php ? you can check your postgres/postgis connections with that.

Comment: Yes I have but as I said I do not know the username and password for it

Comment: * ---------- ---------- Heading
======= ----------------------------------------------------------------------- * Connecting: host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password='********' dbname=postgres
Connection succeeded.
Connecting: host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password='********' dbname=postgres ==============================
Importing with configuration: thsl, public, geog, C:\Users\Madhav\Desktop\thsl\thsl, mode=c, dump=1, simple=1, geography=1, index=1, shape=1, srid=0
Shapefile type: Polygon
PostGIS type: POLYGON[2]
Failed SQL begins: "SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO UTF8;
SET STANDARD

Comment: Confirm that you actually have PostGIS installed in your target database. Run "Select postgis_full_version()"

Comment: how can i check that postgis is installed or not

Comment: where should i run that commend is it in my cmd prompt or from pgsql prompt

Comment: and your tutorila is not working

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the username and password [they show in the image when reading the documentation](http://workshops.opengeo.org/stack-intro/postgis.html)?  (admin/geoserver)

> When you first start the dashboard, it provides a reminder about the
>   default password for accessing GeoServer [....] {followed by the image}

Otherwise, just above step 1 it says:

> **Note**
>
> The PostGIS database has been installed with unrestricted access for
>   local users (users connecting from the same machine as the database is
>   running). *That means that it will accept any password you provide. If
>   you need to connect from a remote computer, the password for the
>   postgres user has been set to postgres*.

Comment: Actually i am working on Ubuntu and u need to create the user and assign password from the terminal and then start working on the PostGIS which does not open as shown in your instructions (which is only for Windows), we need to run pgadmin3 which open the PostGIS and then by entering the newly configured user and password can we create the database. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you created a database without PostGIS extension. 
You should choose the PostGIS template on the 'Definition' tag when creating a new database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to import data in postGIS from shapefile.

http://gis-techniques.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-connect-spatial-databasepostgis.html